# How to align a mask onto an image

Tags: swift, uiimage, calayer, masking

I'm writing in Swift, trying to mask an image using UIImage and CALayer.  The problem is that the mask is scaled and shifted when applied to the image.  I have created my UIImageViewer using the Interface Builder and I have set it to Aspect Fit.  I would like to mask images of arbitrary size.  I generate the mask image to be the same size as the image.  This is a requirement because later I want to add more elements to my mask programmatically and it has to cover the masked image.  Here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var img = UIImage(named: "flowers.png")

    var maskImageSize = CGSizeMake(img!.size.width, img!.size.height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(maskImageSize, false, 0.0)

    var color = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.0)
    color.setFill()
    var rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, img!.size.width, img!.size.height)
    UIRectFill(rect)

    color = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    color.setFill()
    rect = CGRectMake((img!.size.width/2)-50, (img!.size.height/2)-50, 100, 100)
    UIRectFill(rect)

    var maskImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    var maskLayer = CALayer()
    maskLayer.frame = self.imageView.layer.bounds // it'll have the same problem if I set it to self.imageView.layer.frame
    maskLayer.contents = maskImage.CGImage
    maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter

    self.imageView.image = img
    self.imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

I need to know how to align the image mask onto the original image.  Thanks for your help!

I have pretty good screen shots but Stackoverflow doesn't let me to post them because I don't have enough reputation!

Comment: Post the screen shots somewhere else, like imgur, and add links to your question. Someone (heh heh) will come along and put the actual images into your question.

Comment: Here are the links to my mask image, original image and the resulting image:
http://imgur.com/IPXwkES
http://imgur.com/jip5PWc
http://imgur.com/0QPtcOW

Thanks matt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that if you use aspect fit then the size of the image as displayed depends upon both the size of the original image and the size of the image view. What you are trying to do is to imitate what the image view does to the image - and you have no way of knowing exactly what that is.

The best you can do is guess. What you are looking for is the size of the largest rectangle that will fit into your image view's bounds while keeping the aspect ratio of the original image. It happens that if you import the AV Foundation framework, there's a handy function that gives you that information, `AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect` (documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect).

Comment: Thank you!  I'll check that.  This job is tougher than what I thought.

Comment: I thought if I make the image mask the same size as the original image, then whatever happens to the original image by aspect fit parameter would happen to the mask image too!

Comment: No. Think about it. The mask is a layer of the image _view_. That is not what is getting aspect-fitted. What is getting aspect-fitted is the _image_. UIImageView is not UIImage.

Comment: 5 more days to finish the project, it's new year and I'm just forced to rethink my problem :)  Thanks matt and Happy New Year!

Comment: Personally, I still have not even understood what you are _really_ trying to do. All this talk of masks... I'm only talking about masks and aspect ratios because _you_ are talking about them. If I knew what your _real_ goal was, maybe I could recommend a completely different way. But in your questions, you never say (even though I have asked you) what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I want to display an image one piece at a time. Depending on the logic of the program I will show the next pieces. I thought to do it via masks and change the mask image gradually to get the effect I want.  Another way would be to create a new image from scratch and draw the content gradually and display it.  I don't know how to do the second approach either.  I learned to create an image and draw rectangles of solid color in it.  I think my next step is to learn to draw rectangles that its content come from a corresponding rectangle from another image.

Comment: "Another way would be to create a new image from scratch and draw the content gradually and display it" This would be easier. Slicing up an image, in code, into rectangles and drawing an assembly of those rectangles is very straightforward. Again, your first stop should be my book, which teaches you how to draw, and starts by teaching you how to draw pieces of images: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_uiimage_drawing

Comment: Cool!  I'll read your chapter.  Thanks a lot!  Stack overflow is whining about long discussions.  I'll ping you if I need more help.

Comment: We could discuss it further in Chat but you don't have the rep for that yet either. Sorry about that. - You should download my free app Diabelli's Theme. It is a puzzle game that works by dividing a photo up into rectangles (in code) and drawing them separately (in code) - which is very similar to what you want to do.

Comment: I did it!  I read the UIImage Drawing part of your book and it was so easy!  Thanks!  Moving on to implementing my drawing algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem too, and i fixed it in the utilities of the UIImageView. in the **drawing** section i just check the **clip Subview**
like this
[image: clipSubview of the UIImageView]

and the problem is fixed!