# Custom Slider Swift

Tags: ios, swift, slider, calayer, layer

I find this [repo on github](https://github.com/278204/GooeySlider) and I was wondering if someone knows how can I replace the red circle with an image.

If someone wants any more details gladly I will answer to his/her comment and edit if nesessary the question.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Ok unfortunately I didn't make it work as I wanted.
I can show the first image by going to GooeyView to the init function and by adding this line it appears the image, `gooey.contents = ballimage.image?.cgImage`, but it appears it as rectangular (I want it to be circle). For the rest of the images I will search about them and I will post if I got any newer.

Comment: we can put image in CALayer not sure how but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699098/masking-an-image-in-swift-using-calayer-and-uiimage

Comment: Ok I will check it out now. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @EricAya as I saw when you tap the circle is showing to the tapped item and the bar is a single parameter.

Comment: @MikeAlter that solution it  worked! Many thanks I have to adjust it to the proper size now.

Comment: welcome and happy coding