# Shape/mask on UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I was wondering how can this be achieved in Xcode? It's part of a profile, so the header is an actual `UIImageView`, but the curve below it, not sure how to achieve that. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: the image doesn't load for me. what have you tried already?

Comment: not sure why it doesn't load for you, it loads perfectly fine really. I was thinking maybe create a secondary `UIImageView` and use it as a mask on top of the header image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Masking an image in Swift using CALayer and UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699098/masking-an-image-in-swift-using-calayer-and-uiimage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved by giving header view `UIBezierPath` but if you don't want to do that stuff.

I found a cool way of doing.

Your Header view contain a image (Lets say it HeaderImage).

- Make a Image of that shape (Lets say it MaskImage).

  ```
  let path = UIImageView.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "MaskImage"))
  ```
- Than apply this mask to Header Image.

  ```
  HeaderImage.mask = path
  ```

Hope it work for you.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking actually! Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Say that the grey area is built out of a bottom grey rectangle and on top another rectangle with your arc we could do something like this:

Create a `UIBezierPath` in the shape of a circle:

```
let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn:CGRect(x: 0, y: view.bounds.height/2, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)).cgPath
```

Apply it to the top rectangle.

```
let overlay = CAShapeLayer()
overlay.path = path
overlay.fillColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
overlay.shouldRasterize = true
view.layer.addSublayer(overlay)
```

This will create a perfect circle but you can tweak the CGRect's your liking in order to get the shape you want!